# Rx and async nunit test

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive

I'm trying to create an async unit test for the project, but cannot understand how to wait for the async subject to complete:

```
    [Test]
    public async void MicroTest()
    {
        var value = 2;

        var first = new AsyncSubject<int>();
        var second = new AsyncSubject<int>();

        first.Subscribe(_ =>
        {
            value = _;
            second.OnCompleted();
        });

        first.OnNext(1);

        // how to wait for the second subject to complete?

        Assert.AreEqual(value, 1);
    }
```

Sync version of this test is works well:

```
    [Test]
    public void MicroTest()
    {
        var value = 2;

        var first = new Subject<int>();
        var second = new Subject<int>();

        first.Subscribe(_ =>
        {
            value = _;
            second.OnCompleted();
        });

        first.OnNext(1);

        Assert.AreEqual(value, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### AsyncSubject versus Subject

First off, it's worth pointing out that `AsyncSubject<T>` is not an asynchronous version of `Subject<T>`. Both are in fact free-threaded* (see footnote).

`AsyncSubject` is a specialization of `Subject` intended to be used to model an operation that completes asynchronously and returns a single result. It has two noteworthy features:

- Only the last result is published
- The result is cached and is available to observers subscribing after it has completed.

It is used internally in various places, including by the `ToObservable()` extension method defined on `Task` and `Task<T>`.

#### The issue with the test

Recall `AsyncSubject<T>` will only return the final result received. It does this by waiting for OnCompleted() so it knows what the final result is. Because you do not call `OnCompleted()` on `first` your test is flawed as the `OnNext()` handler - the lambda function passed in your Subscribe call - will never be invoked.

Additionally, it is invalid *not* to call `OnNext()` at least once on an `AsyncSubject<T>`, so when you call `await second;` you will get an `InvalidOperationException` if you haven't done this.

If you write your test as follows, all is well:

```
[Test]
public async void MicroTest()
{
    var value = 2;

    var first = new AsyncSubject<int>();
    var second = new AsyncSubject<int>();

    first.Subscribe(_ =>
    {
        // won't be called until an OnCompleted() has
        // been invoked on first
        value = _;
        // you must send *some* value to second
        second.OnNext(_);
        second.OnCompleted();
    });

    first.OnNext(1);
    // you must do this for OnNext handler to be called
    first.OnCompleted(); 

    // how to wait for the second subject to complete
    await second;

    Assert.AreEqual(value, 1);
}
```

#### About asynchronous tests

As a general rule I would avoid writing asynchronous tests that could wait forever. This gets particularly annoying when it causes resource drains on build servers. Use some kind of timeout e.g:

```
await second.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

No need to handle the exception since that is enough for the test to fail.

**I've borrowed this term from [the COM lexicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892259/difference-between-free-threaded-and-thread-safe). In this sense I mean that they, as with most of the Rx framework components, will generally run on whatever thread you happen to invoke their methods on. Being free-threaded doesn't necessarily mean being fully thread safe though. In particular, unlike `AsyncSubject<T>`, `Subject<T>` doesn't protect you from the Rx grammar violation of making overlapping calls to `OnNext`. Use [`Subject.Synchronize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229816(v=vs.103).aspx) or [`Observable.Synchronize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.synchronize(v=vs.103).aspx) for this protection.*